# Dryer doesn't heat or turn off

Tags: dryer

We have a Kenmore dryer that will not turn off, buzz or heat.   It just spins the clothes dry.   Any trouble shooting tips?

Comment: What do you mean, "will not turn off"?  Do you mean it never reaches the end of its cycle?  Do you mean it appears to reach the end, but still keeps tumbling the clothes?  Do you mean that it keeps running even when you open the door?  Note:  If even un-plugging won't stop it, then it may be time to call the Ghost Busters.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason for the dryer not turning off (I'm assuming when the door is opened) is a faulty door switch. Look for a retractable-type switch around the doors perimeter. Unplug the power cord first and pry the switch out. Cut each wire (should be two) to remove. Look for a like kind on line. If the dryer is not heating (I'll assume it uses gas as a heating source) the most likely components are the igniter (the electric coils that ignite the heater gas) or a faulty thermostat or the high-limit switch. If the dryer uses electricity than the trouble may be with the heating coils. If the heating coils don't glow there is probably a break (no continuity) in the coils in which case they will need to be replaced. These are the more common issues that cause a no heat/ no shut-off problem, but can be resolved by a confident DIY-er. Always unplug the appliance before proceeding with repair and/or troubleshooting investigations.